# External library version conflicts

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, dependency-management, jpos

I have two different printer libraries, which are depending on same "java jPOS" library but  with different versions,
[image] 
[image], 
 So both printers referencing on same jpos library because they have same package naming, one of this printers (custom-printer) didn't working on version of new library.
 [image]

 Gradle implimintation: 
`implementation files('/home/daniel/Desktop/JPOS_Service_Objects/CBMjpos.jar')` 
`compile group: 'com.custom', name: 'custom-jcl-printer-driver', version: '1.0'`

How can i solve it without decompiling and renaming this libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found very simple tool to repackage the libraries named (jarjar) - https://github.com/shevek/jarjar